# Insert tabulation in XML document with JAXP

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

i would like to have a good presentation for my XML documents created with JAXP (DOM).

I know that i can read/write my file after its creation, but i would like something more elegant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLOutputter to output formatted XML.

Code:

```
 XMLOutputter XMLOUTPUTTER = new XMLOutputter(
            org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
 XMLOUTPUTTER.outputString(doc);
```